# Change the nested ternary to more verbose conditions

Tags: angular, typescript

Want to move this inside a method and change the nested ternary to more verbose conditions.

.html

```
<button [disabled]="(test.testForm.valid && isDataPresent) ? (this.demoTest.test!=undefined ? !this.demoTest.test.testForm.valid:true):!test.testForm.valid">

</button>
```

Comment: Just create a public method in your .ts and call it.

Comment: Is that possible to set the method to [disabled] attr ?? @RafaelLucini

Answer (score 1):

You can call a method with that ternary:

.ts

```
isDisabled(){
 return (test.testForm.valid && isDataPresent) ? (this.demoTest.test!=undefined ? !this.demoTest.test.testForm.valid:true):!test.testForm.valid
}
```

.html

```
<button [disabled]="isDisabled()">

</button>
```